# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission Denied while Running as Admin

Tags: python, pip, permission-denied

So I get the following error whenever I try to install pip in my cmd for Windows while running as admin:

[image]

Everywhere I've looked says you can fix the problem by just running as admin but when I did it still did not work

Comment: Reinstall python and tick the install pip option , or install pip from 3rd party apps

Comment: try with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip --user`

Answer (score 0):

I think, there's some problem with python or you've messed up things i.e deleted or moved some critical files. First verify ***python*** and ***pip*** installation by, typing this in **cmd**-

```
python -V
```

```
pip -V
```

If your version comes as an output then don't worry. I think you want to upgrade **pip**. Type this in **cmd** to upgrade **pip**-

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

And if not. Since the problem is not clear to me i.e what actually happened. I'll recommend reinstallation. Open **Setting>Apps and features**. Select **Python** and click **Uninstall**. After successful uninstallation. Go to the link below to download the latest version of **Python**-
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-396/

Scroll down and select **Windows Installer(64 bit)**. Download the installer and double-click on it. You can uncheck the box, **Install for other users** if you want. Don't uncheck the box which says **Add python to PATH**. Click on Install Now.
After successful installation, verify that **python** and **pip** are correctly installed or not. By typing executing these to commands(one by one)-

```
python -V
```

```
pip -V
```

Congratulations, Python has been successfully re-installed.